# Open Source Project to learn about systems engineering

Tags: open-source

I am a an engineering student and I want to learn more about systems programming . I wanted to know the various open source projects that I have as options to learn from about the same. The Linux Kernel Project is very stable and has a very large code base.I wanted to know about projects that would not take much time to get boot strapped and start contributing.

Thanks

Comment: belongs in programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: please note that _systems engineering_ is completely different from operating systems programming, so the title was a bit misleading

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) operating system, and its corresponding book [Operating System Design and Implementation](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0131429388,00%2ben-USS_01DBC.html) by Tanenbaum.

Minix is really a minimalist OS expressly designed explicitly for teaching these concepts.  Contributing may be less useful, but still possible.

I use and have used Linux in production for 16 years and love it, but since it's a production quality, highly-tuned system, it is much more baroque to understand the source, and Minix is much more accessible and straightforward for teaching these concepts.

[CS162](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/archives.html) at UC Berkeley is also pretty good.